# Array of UITableViewCells to be reused in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate `n` number of cells (corresponding to `indexpath.row`) are created and are added to an array `cellsArray` how to reuse each cell in the array, when `cellsArray` count is 7? (want to reuse the cells as a batch of 7)

```
FINameCell *cell = nil;
if ([FINameCellcells count] > indexPath.row)
{
    cell = [FINameCellcells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FINameCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [cellsArray addObject:cell];
}
```

Comment: `UITableView` already caches cells.  Why would you do it yourself?

Comment: You should use UITableView's built in `dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier`.  You can create multiple reusable cells types in that method as well (I see that you are using two different ones).

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to manually load cells from NIBs these days. The way to do that is to call UITableView's `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` with the cell being either already defined as prototype cell in IB or by associating the cell via `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier` beforehand.

After that, don't worry about cell reuse, it's going to be all automatic.